# Export SAS model

Tags: sas, predictive

I built a predictive model on SAS using their Model Studio. (My first one!)

Everything worked, but I can't publish it, see the model, test any other data source against it, or export it. What do I need to do next?

I built this using a trial of their graphical software, so command prompts probably won't help me much.

Thanks for any input!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXa2.png)

Comment: Please add screenshots. Can you confirm which SAS product you are using: SAS Enterprise Guide, Forecast  Studio, E Miner,  SAS Studio, Viya ..?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot of what I get when I try to publish. I'm using a trial of SAS Model Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it looks like your Publish Server is not setup/configured. I assume that's because you are using a Trial Version.

Comment: So from a trial version I cannot publish? I'm not seeing any options for a Publish Server, so I would assume that's the case.

Comment: Correct, if the trial version is hosted by sas they wouldn't give you a publish server.